# Why does the TARDIS spin around?

Tags: doctor-who, spaceship, technology, tardis

Why does the TARDIS spin during flight? I'm looking for *both* in and out-of-universe explanations? Has it always spun like that? If not, when did the spinning start?

[image: spinning TARDIS gif]

---

<sub>Also, I haven't seen series 9 yet, so please hide any spoilers.</sub>

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/gallifrey/comments/1ctilv/why_does_the_tardis_spin_whilst_in_flight/

Comment: I should also note that Clara/Ashildr's TARDIS was spinning as well. Also, Doctor's TARDIS wasn't spinning in his first ep with Donna, or 11th Doctor's first ep, or when Clara was looking down on London for "hidden alleys". It appears that Doctor can actually control the spinning if he chooses to, but he doesn't, as a spinning TARDIS is more phun. Also I want that thingy from the gif. I want it real bad.

Comment: I don't have any quotes to back this up (so this is a comment rather than an answer) but I believe this was first introduced in the 2005 reboot. I assume it is meant to convey the idea of the TARDIS lurching around uncontrollably. I think that this was when (and for the same reason) we started seeing the occupants being flung around the control room as they traveled.

Comment: @Blackwood - If you follow the reddit link above, you'll see that the TARDIS spinning significantly pre-dates the reboot series. - [01:57](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2aak3r_frontier-in-space-pt-1_shortfilms) for example.

Comment: @Gallifreian: From the question: _"Also, I haven't seen series 9 yet, so please hide any spoilers."_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit surely you won't be kind enough to point out my spoiler?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I added the "no spoilers" part after seeing Gallifreian's comment.

Comment: @RedCaio: Mmm so you did. RIP for the spoiler! That was a nice big surprise for me when watching the show.

Comment: @Gallifreian: I don't understand your question, sorry.

Comment: @Valorum In your link, just FYI (and of course any one else who reads this), I think I disagree with the comment that the TARDIS was spinning in "The Mind Robber". In this episode the TARDIS is out of control and about to explode, with cliff hanger of the Doctor, Jamie and Zoe hanging on to the console (with no exterior TARDIS shell) that was rotating. I don't believe there was any implication that the TARDIS spinning was part of its usual manner of travel. Certainly, in the clip there are no stars shown (not in normal space) for which it to be rotating with respect to.

Comment: @jim - There are other relevant examples; [Timecode 01:08](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xsyw9i_the-trial-of-a-time-lord-the-mysterious-planet-part-1_shortfilms), for instance

Comment: @jim - And [02:40](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x7tvqf_pyramids-of-mars-p1_people). I'm sure I've seen it in older (black and white) serials too...

Comment: @Valorum I'm not objecting that it was seen in "Trial of a Timelord". In my answer I provide the BBC view that the first time it was seen was in the third Doctor story "The Time Monster". I also admit I thought I'd seen it in the first Doctor story, "The Chase" (but this proved wrong, when you see both the TARDIS and Dalek time ship in flight neither spin) and also the second Doctor story "The Web of Fear" (again wrong, the TARDIS was caught in a web and was motionless in space). Around the 1970's theoretical physicists were looking at rotating cylinders as a means of time travel.

Answer (score 5):

The TARDIS spinning was a very early and inexpensive special effect.  The earliest I recall seeing it was in some Patrick Troughton stories, but it may have dated back earlier, to the Hartnell era.  It was accomplished by placing the TARDIS model on a small motorized turntable; then the turntable and the background were replaced by the starfield.  The net effect was to show the ship in motion in outer space, without requiring anything that would require moving the camera, or the backdrop, or the model.

There was never a clear idea in *Doctor Who* of how the TARDIS moved.  Since it dematerializes and rematerializes, it doesn't make a ton of sense that it should be physically present in outer space while it is traveling from planet to planet.  On the other hand, somebody on the production staff must have decided that they wanted to include the ship moving physically through outer space.  It gives a least some measure of feeling to the idea that the TARDIS is really going somewhere while it is in transit.

As I understand it, the rotating TARDIS effect was quite iconic among British fans of the show.  (That was not the case at all in America, when *Doctor Who* became popular there in the 1980s.  The '60s-era shows where the effect was used were mostly lost, and those that remained were not shown very much in comparison to the episodes featuring the third through seventh Doctors.)  It was sufficiently famous that it featured as a gag in a behind-the-scenes parody of "An Unearthly Child" that ran in the twentieth anniversary issue of the official *Doctor Who* magazine.  Appearances of the rotating TARDIS in the new show must be allusions to the original cheap effect from half a century ago.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the first time the TARDIS was shown spinning was in the Tom Baker story "Pyramids of Mars". However, this link suggests that the first time was the last episode of the Jon Pertwee story "Frontier in Space" (see the comments by [galacticprobe](http://tardisbuilders.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=g2bc95u8tqddnrvcgqr00d5ae3&topic=259.msg72798#msg72798)) (it had been difficult to check up on this, since when use the search term "spinning TARDIS" mostly get links to the toy).

However, according to the [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/5tZpzHLpN2dShwQ7wmDnp8G/the-fourth-dimension): The first story to have the TARDIS rotating as it travels was in the Jon Pertwee story "The Time Monster":"For the first time, the Doctor identifies the realm through which the TARDIS travels as being the ‘vortex’, a term that would be regularly used throughout the rest of the series. *It’s also the first time that we see the TARDIS exterior spinning as it travels*. This would become a standard in future stories".

As far as the science is concerned, have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipler_cylinder) about Tipler cylinders which involve rotation of sorts.

Comment: The TARDIS was shown spinning in space in multiple Troughton stories.

Comment: @Buzz Can you give any documented examples?

Answer (score -3):

My idea was that The Doctor made TARDIS spinning and shaking during flights in purpose, because he did not want to get bored. At least after some lines he had with River while she was flying the TARDIS by the book... "Where's the fun in that?".

Comment: The whole thing would just be a blue boringer.